# roll over effect, show another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an href image in this markup.

```
<div class="imgdiv">
   <a class="imga" href="http://destination.com">
      <img src="http://image.com/image.jpg" width="100" height="100">
   </a>
</div>
```

When I hover over it, I want to show another image in the top right corner. Is this doable with css? or do I need javascript for that?

My CSS looks like this but it still doesn't work

```
a.imga:hover {
   background-image: url('over.png');
   background-position: top;
   z-index:3;
}
```

Comment: Check out CSS :hover http://htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/pseudoclasses/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  CSS Sprites, [check out this screen-cast](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/43-how-to-use-css-sprites/) from css-tricks.com on how to use them.

Answer (score 4):

```
**Here is the solution you can try**

<div class="imgdiv">
       <a class="imga" href="http://destination.com">
          <img src="URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE" onmouseover="this.src='URL OF THE SECOND IMAGE GOES HERE'" onmouseout="this.src='URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE'" width="100" height="100">
       </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can do it with CSS, but insted of img tag use a DIV with a background image

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

CSS style

```
        #image{
            width: 100px; //Image height
            height: 100px; //Image width
            background: url('') 0 0 no-repeat; //Give your image path here
        }

        #image:hover{
            background: url('') 0 0 no-repeat; 
        }
```

Comment: Note that `:hover` does not work in IE6 for anything other than links :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: Yes IE6 not support. Then we can do this using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:hover` pseduo selector on the div with class `imgdiv` with `background-position` set appropriately to show on the top right corner. Off course, you should apply `background-image` to the div first.

Note that `:hover` does not work in IE6 for anything other than links. However, you can overcome this limitation by using javascript/jquery.

Comment: @zmol: Try to use `z-index` property with greater value on your div.